# How to fire "focusout" event when focus lost of input placed in table?

Tags: html, angular, input, angular2-template, lost-focus

I have a `table` where `input`is placed:

```
<tr *ngFor="let persons of ReceivedData">
  <td *ngFor="let person of persons">

    <div *ngIf="person.personId === editRowId && person.editable === true ">
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="person.CarCount" 
               (focusout)="focusOutFunction()"/>
    </div>                            
    <div *ngIf="person.editable === false " (click)="toggle(person)">
        {{ person.CarCount ? person.CarCount : '-' }}
    </div>

  </td>
<tr>
```

But the `focusout` event isn't fired. 
Here's the method handling the `focusout` function:

```
focusOutFunction() {        
}
```

Interestingly `focusout` works perfectly when `input` is not placed inside `table`:

```
<input type="number" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()" />
```

How can I fire an event when I focus inside of the table?

Comment: Might need to use (blur) for this case.

Comment: You're not receiving any browser errors?

Comment: Here's a working plnkr of focusout proc'ing inside a table with a similar setup as you have: https://plnkr.co/edit/Bqxnf3aGb0DdSEGYgIoc?p=preview

Comment: @Z.Bagley `(blur)` is also not working. Moreover, there are no broweser errors.

Comment: @Z.Bagley thanks for example. But I pull my head, it doesn't work on my browser. What can I do?

Comment: Z.Bagleys example works fine in my browser. If his doesn't work for you, then maybe there is something wrong with your browser. Try a different one.

Comment: @JosephCho it is the most popupar browser - Chrome. I cannot use another browser.

Comment: I am also using chrome... Bagleys example doesn't work for you? That is very strange since it works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bqxnf3aGb0DdSEGYgIoc?p=preview) of `focusout` proc'ing inside a table with a similar setup as you have. The other key is to include an `autofocus` attribute:

```
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="person.CarCount" 
           (focusout)="focusOutFunction()" autofocus/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `blur` event to get focus out.

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="person.CarCount" 
               (blur)="focusOutFunction()"/>
```